# Create new Script within <div> from C# and Reload newly created Script

Tags: c#

I would like to implement the following, which would appear to be fairly easy, but I have been searching for a working example without success.

i) I have an HTML  Tag in an aspx Page with an identification:

```
<div id="demo" runat="server">
```

ii) This  Tag contains the following Script Tag, which itself has an identification:

```
<script id="scriptdemo" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myurl.com/myquery"></script>
```

iii) I have an AJAX call which calls a Server Function (which is working without any issue)

iv) From that Server Function, I would like to either modify the “src” Attribute of the Script, or create and insert a new script in the existing division with a new src if this solution is easier to implement.

v) After executing the Server Code contained within the Server Function, the flow is properly passed back to the client (here again, I do not have any issue with this process).

vi) Once back on the client, I would like to refresh/reload the newly created script (or updated src attribute) using JavaScript/AJAX (either standard Javascript or JQuery).

Would someone have a working example of such code?

Comment: When you say refresh, you just mean run new code from a newly created script?

Comment: Hi Rob, Yes that is correct. Basically, I would like to reload the url, which will contain a new query ("http://www.myurl.com/MyNewQuery").

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

It's basically shorthand for `$.ajax` with datatype as "script". This will load a script file for you, and give you the chance to run a callback when it's done.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your/ServerMethodThatReturnsScript",
   dataType: "script",
   success: successCallback
});
```

becomes

```
$.getScript("your/ServeRMethodThatreturnsScript", function() { /* some success callback */ });
```

In the event you can't do this but CAN make an ajax call to your server, you can use the `eval` method to execute any string that is in the form of javascript:

```
eval("/*some javascript*/");
```

Comment: Hi Rob,
Sorry I should have specified that I cannot used this method (I had initially planned to do it this way), since my url is not on the same domain, and thus the browser ignores the script (same-origine policy), which explains why I am going back to the server in order to create a new script.
Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative to this technique for security reasons. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hi Rob, The policy constitutes a security one (as you must know), which is respected by browsers (on the client side), enabling scripts running on a page to be executed only if their origin is the same, for security reasons. Thus, if the script is changed on the server side and sent back to the client the policy is respected, for its origin will be the same.